# How do I solve Reporting role log errors related to reference data?

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, reporting, infrastructure

I use SIF to install XP1 packages for all Sitecore 9.0.2 server roles. When I look in the logs of the Reporting instance, I see exceptions, such as:

#### Dependency injection can't find an implementation of `IReferenceDataClient`

```
11420 16:41:21 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Unable to resolve service for type 'Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.Core.IReferenceDataClient' while attempting to activate 'Sitecore.Marketing.Operations.Xdb.ReferenceData.Service.Definitions.Profiles.ProfileDefinitionReferenceDataRepository'.
Source: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   bei System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   bei Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerFactory.GetDefinitionManager[TDefinition]()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<.ctor>b__4()
   bei System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   bei System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.InitializeProfilesWithDefaultValues()
   bei System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   bei System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.InitializeProfiles()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField..ctor(Field innerField)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.GetTrackingField(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.FindTrackingField(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.HasTracking(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestTrackingInformation.IsTrackedRequest()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule.IsSessionRequired()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule.ContextPostMapRequestHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

#### Dependency injection can't find an implementation of `IReferenceDataProvider`

```
29048 16:56:33 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Unable to resolve service for type 'Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.Core.Repository.IReferenceDataProvider' while attempting to activate 'Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.Service.Repository.ReferenceDataRepository'.
Source: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   bei System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   bei Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerFactory.GetDefinitionManager[TDefinition]()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<.ctor>b__4()
   bei System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   bei System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.InitializeProfilesWithDefaultValues()
   bei System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   bei System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.InitializeProfiles()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField..ctor(Field innerField)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.GetTrackingField(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.FindTrackingField(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.HasTracking(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestTrackingInformation.IsTrackedRequest()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule.IsSessionRequired()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule.ContextPostMapRequestHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

#### Dependency injection can't find the connection string `xdb.referencedata`

```
14920 17:00:59 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.
Source: mscorlib
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   bei Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   bei Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   bei Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   bei Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   bei Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.SqlServer.Xmgmt.Configuration.ServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddSqlServerReferenceDataProvider>b__0_0(IServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   bei Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerFactory.GetDefinitionManager[TDefinition]()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<.ctor>b__4()
   bei System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   bei System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.InitializeProfilesWithDefaultValues()
   bei System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   bei System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.InitializeProfiles()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField..ctor(Field innerField)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.GetTrackingField(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.FindTrackingField(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.HasTracking(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestTrackingInformation.IsTrackedRequest()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule.IsSessionRequired()
   bei Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule.ContextPostMapRequestHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: Unable to find connection string with name 'xdb.referencedata'
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.SqlServer
   bei Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.SqlServer.SqlServerReferenceDataProvider.ResolveConnectionString(String connectionStringOrName)
   bei Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.SqlServer.SqlServerReferenceDataProvider..ctor(String connectionStringOrName, ILogger`1 logger, ITvpConverter tvpConverter, IRetryManager retryManager)
   bei Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.SqlServer.SqlServerReferenceDataProvider..ctor(String connectionStringOrName, ILogger`1 logger, IRetryManager retryManager)
```

How do I configure Sitecore Reporting correctly to prevent these errors from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Reporting role is configured incorrectly out of the box. It does not have the Reference Data subsystem enabled. Here's how you can fix this.

#### Step 1

1. Open the file `Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.Service.config` located under `\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Xdb.ReferenceData.Service\`
2. Update `<sitecore role:require="Processing or Standalone">`
   to `<sitecore role:require="Processing or Standalone or Reporting">`

#### Step 2:

1. Open the file `Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.SqlServer.config` located under `\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Xdb.ReferenceData.SqlServer\`
2. Update `<sitecore role:require="Processing or Standalone">`
   to `<sitecore role:require="Processing or Standalone or Reporting">`

#### Step 3:

1. Open the file `\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config`
2. Add a new connection string named `xdb.referencedata` and point it to the relevant SQL database. You can look up the value of this connection string on your CM instance.